# Iframe’s document is undefined or null

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

My assignment is to create two iframes. In one have a catalog where you characteristics of shoes, socks and shirts. The data from the 1 iframe is not moving over to the second iframe.

It says *“`document` is `undefined` or `null`”*.

```
function doit() {
  window.frames[0].document.form1.txtprice.value = window.frames[1].document.form2.priceResult.value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To access the document in an iframe you use the [`contentDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentDocument) property.

```
  window.frames[0].contentDocument.form1.txtprice.value = window.frames[1].contentDocument.form2.priceResult.value;
```

Also, this will only work if both iframes are from the same domain as the original page.